# Windows forms app (visual studio 2010) compatibility issues

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, clr

My task is to make a simple application that connects to the internet (using Wininet) and downloads a text file. It then displays the data in a listBox widget. The requirement was to make a GUI based application, so I used Windows Forms in Visual Studio Express 2010.

The application runs fine on my PC, however I realized that it runs only on my PC. I installed .Net 4 and Visual Studio 2010 redistributables on another PC and it worked fine there. Now, the person for whom I'm making this wants maximum compatibility on windows PCs. I'm totally stuck here.. should I switch to an older version of VSE?

From what I could search, using /MT instead of /MD would cause the application to link statically, however my app also uses /CLR and these are incompatible.

Any ideas?

Note: I've previously made a similar app (downloading and displaying) with console output and it works perfectly fine everywhere.

Comment: You cannot use /MT in a Winforms app.  This can't have anything to do with "maximum compatibity", surely he's asking for an installer so he doesn't have to install the dependencies himself.  There's no support for creating installers in the Express edition, you'll need to either update or use another tool.  Like WiX or InstallShield.

Comment: The app itself is very simple and he wants only the app in a single exe file. By enabling /MT, I thought static linking would be possible and hence compatibility could be ensured but as it turns out, WinForms doesn't accept /MT.

Comment: @HansPassant: As a side question, is it possible to install the dependencies as a background operation (not visible to the user) in the installer?

Comment: Installers show a progress bar, surely you've seen it.  And just one file, setup.exe

Comment: "Now, the person for whom I'm making this wants maximum compatibility on windows PCs." -- That means you should drop .NET Framework altogether, because it won't work on Windows 95. If by "maximum compatibility" you don't actually mean "maximum compatibility", and I'm assuming you don't, please specify what you do mean.

Comment: @hvd: I'm sorry, I mean compatibility on Windows XP and later.

Comment: @tecfreak Is it a safe assumption for you that all service packs have been installed? .NET 4 isn't supported before XP SP3. If that is a safe assumption, no problem, otherwise you might consider .NET 3.5.

Comment: @hvd: Well, I'd like to go for .Net 3.5: What should I do for that? Will I be able to build for .Net 3.5 in my PC?

Comment: @HansPassant: I can get Visual Studio 2010 Professional as part of my IEEE student membership. Does it have the support for creating installers? Or is it only available with commercial licenses?
As a side question: Will the installer have the ability to install another app (eg: a toolbar) during the installation of the main app?

Comment: @tecfreak It's an option in your project properties. About VS2010Pro: to the best of my knowledge, the academic and commercial editions have the same functionality, it's just that commercial use of the academic edition is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Dependens on what is meant by "maximum compatibility on windows PCs".  If you can bundle the required redistributables, your program should run (as you found on the second PC), as long as the windows on the PC is capable of executing the binaries (e.g. not a 32 bit PC trying to execute 64 bit binaries)

Comment: I don't think distributing resdistributables is acceptable. He wants a simple, single .exe file.

Comment: You cannot run a .Net program without the .Net framework present...  It's akin to tring to run a java bytecode without the JVM present

Comment: Of course I'm not keen on running the app without the framework. My question is whether I should go for an older version of VSE (2008?) as most PCs today have the 2008 redistributables installed? Will it use the older .Net version?

Comment: The .Net redistributables are unlike the java virtual machine: you need specific minimum versions of the framework to run your program.  This means that compiling for an earlier framework will work on computer with both the earlier and the latter framework, but the other way around.  This still does not mean that all Windows will have any specific (minimum) version of the .Net framework.

Comment: @Attila You need to specifically check and mark a .NET 2 as compatible with .NET 4 in order to be able to run it when only .NET 4 is installed. There are some valid .NET 2 applications that behave differently in .NET 4, which is why it cannot be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**I have been in your situation.**

I can give you my free .NET-application-runner (RunNetApp.exe) that automatically installs .NET Framework 4 before running your application for the first time. If the framework is already installed on target machine, it only runs your application.

I also suggest changing application's framework to ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile". It's setup is about 40MB (in comparison to 200MB of full ".NET framework 4").

Is it helpful?